# How to configure FilterParameter correctly in ASP.net SqlDataSource in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is an ASP.net c# WebForms application.  I am using VS2019.

I am attempting to add a FilterParameter to my SqlDataSource in the code behind.  But I'm getting the following error message:

> Could not find control 'txtLN' in ControlParameter 'LN'.

Likewise, I get a similar error when I attempt to filter using 'txtBN'.

Below is my code:

```
protected void btnFilterClients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fexp = " LIKE '%{0}%'";

        SqlDataSource sdsGvClients = new SqlDataSource();
        sdsGvClients.ID = "sdsGvClients";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(sdsGvClients);
        sdsGvClients.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataSet;
        sdsGvClients.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        sdsGvClients.SelectCommand = "SELECT c.Id, c.FN, c.LN, c.BN, ct.ClientType FROM Clients c INNER JOIN tlClientTypes ct ON c.ClientType = ct.Id";
        sdsGvClients.SelectParameters.Clear();
        sdsGvClients.FilterParameters.Clear();

        if (txtLN.Text.Length == 0 && txtBN.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            gvClients.DataSource = sdsGvClients;
            gvClients.DataBind();
        }

        else if (txtLN.Text.Length != 0 && txtBN.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            sdsGvClients.FilterExpression = "LN" + fexp;
            sdsGvClients.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter("LN", "txtLN", "Text"));
            gvClients.DataSource = sdsGvClients;
            gvClients.DataBind();
        }

        else if (txtLN.Text.Length == 0 && txtBN.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            sdsGvClients.FilterExpression = "BN" + fexp;
            sdsGvClients.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter("BN", "txtBN", "Text"));
            gvClients.DataSource = sdsGvClients;
            gvClients.DataBind();
        }

        else if (txtLN.Text.Length != 0 && txtBN.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Please choose one or the other, or neither.";
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

EDIT
Below is the markup.

```
<div class="row">
    Filter by contact:<br />
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="lblLN" runat="server" Text="Last Name: " AssociatedControlID="txtLN" CssClass="control-label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLN" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="lblBN" runat="server" Text="Company Name: " AssociatedControlID="txtBN" CssClass="control-label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBN" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>            
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <asp:Button ID="btnFilterClients" runat="server" Text="Filter" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnFilterClients_Click" />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlAddNewClient" runat="server" Text="Add New Client" DataTextField="Add New Client" CssClass="btn btn-success" NavigateUrl="~/Business/NewClient.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <h3>Search Results</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-mg-12 col-lg-12">
        <asp:GridView 
            ID="gvClients" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            AllowPaging="true" 
            AllowSorting="True" 
            DataKeyNames="Id">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Id"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FN" HeaderText="FN" SortExpression="FN"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LN" HeaderText="LN" SortExpression="LN"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BN" HeaderText="BN" SortExpression="BN"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientType" HeaderText="ClientType" SortExpression="ClientType"></asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I just gave up and went with:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="sdsGvClients" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>' 
    SelectCommand="SELECT c.Id, c.FN, c.LN, c.BN, ct.ClientType FROM Clients c INNER JOIN tlClientTypes ct ON c.ClientType = ct.Id"
    FilterExpression="LN Like '%{0}%' AND BN Like '%{1}%'">     
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLN" Name="LN" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBN" Name="BN" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But I would still like to know how to get this working using the .cs file.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a control named `txtLN`. Can you show your markup?

Comment: Which line in the code throws exception?

Comment: sdsGvClients.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter("LN", "txtLN", "Text"));  I have also tried changing txtLN to MainContent_txtLN, but I get the same error.  It's just not finding the textbox.